# How to attribute/cite QuickMapServices Google satellite layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, google-maps, license, quickmapservices

I work for an ecological consultancy company. I’ve used a Google satellite layer inserted using the QuickMapServices plugin in QGIS. I’m going to insert the figure into a report for a client. What is the correct attribution/citation for the Google satellite layer please?

Answer (score 3):

Following the [Google Attribution Guidelines](https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide/) :

> All uses of Google Maps and Google Earth content must provide
>   attribution to both Google and our data providers. We do not approve
>   of any use of content without proper attribution, in any circumstance.
>   We require attribution when the content is shown. Requests for
>   exceptions will not be answered or granted.
>
> **Where can I find the attribution information ?**
>
> You can find the attribution in the line(s) shown on the bottom of the
>   content in the products along with copyright notices, such as “Map
>   data ©2018 Google”. Note that the exact text of the attribution
>   changes based on geography and content type. The attribution text must
>   be legible to the average viewer or reader.
>
> In Google Maps, you’ll find our data providers listed in the bottom
>   right corner of the map. Here, Google is the data provider:
>
> [image: gmaps_attribution]
>
> **What does the attribution text need to say?**
>
> If you’re not using the text provided directly on Google Maps and
>   Google Earth imagery, the text of your attribution must say the name
>   “Google” and the relevant data provider(s), such as “Map data: Google,
>   DigitalGlobe”.
>
> You may customize the style and placement of the attribution text, as
>   long as the text is legible to the average viewer or reader. Note that
>   Google logos cannot be used in-line (for example, "These maps from
>   [Google logo].")

**Solution 1** : go to [Google Maps](https://www.google.fr/maps) at the location of the maps with the correct zoom level and copy the bottom-right attribution text.

**Solution 2** : refer to the Google Guidelines and cite "*Map data: Google, list all other data providers*".

Comment: And of course check if your use case fall under the "fair use" utilisation of google data

Answer (score 1):

Layers added through the QuickMapServices plugin come with attribution information in the Layer Properties.

[image]

As you can see it's not completely up to date (copyright date is listed as 2015) but there's also a link provided to attribution guidelines on the data provider's website.